# Git push local repo to ssh server

Tags: git, ssh

**What I need**:
I am using mingw2 under Win 10.
I am barely experienced with git.
I have a directory in my PC1 with several C/C++ projects.
I mean to have another working PC2 where I can also develop, and use git for "smart merging" changes in one or the other PC.
PC1 is not open for inbound connections, so I can only *push from PC1*->PC2, or *pull from PC1*<-PC2 (but not the other way).

**What I tried**:
I created a git repo in PC1 with the existing files.

```
[PC1]$ ls -a1
./
../
.git/
.gitignore
arrays/
...
```

Now I mean to setup a "copy" via git in a remote computer PC2 with Ubuntu 22.04LTS to which I can connect via ssh.
I need the files and directories to show up in PC2, so I can also develop there.

I managed to `git push` PC1->PC2 (see below the evidence for that).
Now in PC2 I only have a `.git` directory, but none of the files I actually pushed.

```
[PC2]$ ls -a1
./
../
.git/
```

I expected to see here `arrays/` and other directories/files.

**Was I wrong in expecting this?**

**What could the problem and solution be?**

**Note**: I did the same against a repo created in Github (setup with an SSH Deployed Key and added as an ssh repo) and files show up in the Github repo.
I am not sure if the way of setting up the repo in Github is something different from what I did in PC2.

---

Why I infer I have "git connectivity" PC1->PC2?

To setup my repo in PC2, I executed

```
[PC2]$ mkdir ~/c_cpp
```

In the local PC1

```
[PC1]$ git remote add pc2 ssh://user1@pc2/home/user1/c_cpp
[PC1]$ git branch -M main
[PC1]$ git push -u pc2 main
fatal: '/home/user1/c_cpp' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

(note: `pc2` is defined in `~/.ssh/config` in PC1). Guided by the error message, in PC2 I executed

```
[PC2]$ cd ~/c_cpp
[PC2]$ git init
```

and in PC1

```
[PC1]$ git push -u pc2 main
Enumerating objects: 96, done.
Counting objects: 100% (96/96), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (87/87), done.
Writing objects: 100% (96/96), 66.71 KiB | 36.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 96 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ssh://user1@pc2/home/user1/c_cpp
 * [new branch]      main -> main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'pc2'.
```

To test if I have "git connectivity" PC1->PC2, I tried a couple of dummy commits, by

1. Changing some tracked file.
2. Commit

```
    [PC1]$ git commit -m "dummy commit"
```

3. Push

```
    [PC1]$ git push -u pc2 main
    Enumerating objects: 9, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 422 bytes | 14.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    To ssh://user1@pc2/home/user1/c_cpp
       5b9b83a..13f4d01  main -> main
    Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'pc2'.
```

I repeated the procedure renaming `~/c_cpp` to `~/c_cpp.bak` in PC2, and `git push` failed.
After renaming back `~/c_cpp.bak` to `~/c_cpp`, `git push` succeeded.
Plus, the modification date of `~/c_cpp` changes with every `git push`.
All this works the same when using either `pc2`, `user1@pc2` or `user1@<ip-of-pc2>` for the remote location.

So I conclude `git push` is somehow working.

Comment: I don't understand where is your problem; to be able to push on PC2, you need to initialize the directory on PC2 (with git init). Git is not scp, is pushed things in an already existent repository. You may also clone (git clone) PC1 repo from PC2, then push from 1 => 2 will work.

Comment: @OznOg - Please see edited OP, perhaps the problem is clearer. 
I did `git init` and `git push`.
I cannot `git clone` from PC2, as PC1 is not open for inbound connections. But that should not be a hurdle for what I mean to accomplish.

Comment: sorry I still dont get it. what is the problem? IMHO everything is behaving as expected, so hard to help... What is making you think something is wrong?

Comment: @OznOg - I expanded the OP.
As mentioned, things are not behaving *as I expected* (likely my expectations are wrong), and the outcome is not useful for my needs.
Hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that on PC2, you pushed your commits into the Git repo (inside the `.git` folder) but you don't have anything checked out, so you won't see the files there. If you do a `git log --all` on PC2, you should see references to your commit(s).

However, it's not a very good idea to push to a regular sandbox. You'll find your life will be easier if you push to a bare repo on PC2 instead of a regular sandbox. What you did works, but it's prone to cause problems later. In particular, if you do a checkout in that repo on PC2, then you'll probably get an error when you try to push the same branch to PC2 later.

What I would recommend is that on PC2, you use `git init --bare` instead of `git init` for the repo there, so it's not a sandbox, but just a bare repo.

If you need to use the files on PC2 as well, clone that bare repo into a sandbox you can use normally afterwards.

##### More details

When you're going to work with ssh, you should have a directory where you store your repos to use as remote, and then somewhere else where you use them.

1. Create the remote on PC2 as a bare repo, say in `git_root`.

   ```
   cd $HOME
   mkdir -p git_root
   cd git_root
   git init --bare my_repo.git
   ```
2. Push to it from PC1 as you did, with this remote name:

   ```
   ssh://user1@pc2/home/user1/git_root/my_repo.git
   ```
3. Clone it to a regular sandbox on PC2 where you can inspect its contents

   ```
   cd my_sandboxes
   git clone ~/git_root/my_repo.git
   ```

   Now you will have a folder called `my_repo` which will be a regular sandbox when you can see and edit your files, make and commit changes, and push them, just like in your sandbox on PC1.

Comment: I am not aware of the differences between a bare repo and a regular sandbox.
And I wouldn't foresee the potential problems.
I have edited the OP to make clearer what I am after.
I would appreciate if you could list the proper steps for what I need, in addition to the explanation...

Comment: I assure you, if you try to see the files in the regular sandbox on PC2, you will encounter the problems I am warning you about. Please take the time to learn about bare repos, it's going to be time well invested.

Comment: If you don't want to redo the remote on PC2 but you want to inspect the files, clone it into another sandbox. There, the files will be visible as you expect.

Comment: By the way, about GitHub. GitHub is not Git, it's a different piece of software built on top of Git, which add all this viewing interface you're familiar with, and a lot more. When you use ssh to push to a remote that just exists as a directory, you give up all those features GitHub implements.

Comment: In any case, I've added more details to my answer, as requested. Hopefully they will help you understand how it all works.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this and other sources.